# Changes not reflecting on live - the Scripts and Style Sheets field in Head HTML

Tags: magento2.3

I'm trying to add the Google Tag Manager script in Content -> Design -> Configuration -> Store View -> Head Html -> Scripts and Style Sheets but when i try to save the code, the field doesn't update.
Preconditions

Magento Edition: Community - Version: 2.3

Steps to reproduce

```
Go to Content -> Design -> Configuration -> Store View -> Head Html
Add the script in Scripts and Style Sheets field
Save
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:
Flushing Magento Cache
Re-deploying static content
If you use varnish, you can restart it